# GraphicsGrid, GraphicsRow, GraphicsColumn applications

Tags: graphics

I often use `Grid`, `Row` and `Column` and have used them to arrange multiple Graphics objects. Then I recently found `GraphicsGrid`, `GraphicsRow`, `GraphicsColumn`, but I don't understand what they can do that is difficult or impossible to do using `Grid`, `Row`, `Column`. When are the special forms for Graphics needed?

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4YAH0.gif) is simple comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GraphicsRow` produces a `Graphics` output, while `Row` does not; the same applies to columns and grids. This means that `GraphicsRow` can be altered with the options available in `Plot` etc. For example, let's take

```
plots = Table[Plot[Sin[x + i π/2], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True], {i, 0, 1}]
```

Then one can do e.g.

```
grow = GraphicsRow[plots, ImageSize -> Full]
Head@grow
```

> Graphics

where the `ImageSize` option actually makes an effect, while

```
row = Row[plots, ImageSize -> Full]
Head@row
```

> Row

does not.

I'm quite sure that the formatting of `Row` can also be performed in other ways, but in case of `GraphicsRow` it's straightforward. 'Row' can handle any type of object, while `GraphicsRow` is designed explicitly for `Graphics`.